# jQuery Dialog UI not working in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following Jquery code that works great inside my .aspx page using FF or Chrome.  However, in IE9, when I click on the button that is supposed to open the dialog box, it just seems to refresh the entire page and nothing happens.

I am using these versions:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Here is my jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $("#btnSearch").click(function () {
        $("#gvBox").show();
    });
    $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 400,
        width: 650,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Transfer": function () {
                var bValid = true;
                allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
                if (bValid) {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close: function () {
            allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
        },
        open: function () {
            {
                $(this).parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
            }
        }
    });
    $("#btnTransfer").button().click(function () {
        $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
        return false;
    });
    return false;
});
```

And here is my button that opens the dialog box:

```
<button id="btnTransfer">Transfer Ownership</button>&nbsp;
```

Are there any tricks to getting this to work with IE?

Comment: probably won't fix your issue.. but why do you have double brackets here `open:function(){{`

Comment: wirey - good catch, I removed the extra brackets but it still doesn't work. MBJ - what missing event handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#btnTransfer").button().on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
});
```

...instead of `return false;`

Comment: mmm...I think this is a start.  It still works fine in FF, but doesn't work in IE...however the page in IE is no longer refreshing...which is good because it shouldn't refresh when that button is clicked.

Comment: Try removing the last `return false;` before the last `});` closing.

Comment: `return false` does both preventDefault & stopPropogation, so unless you had some events linked to your click further down (which it was stopping), must be the only reason this worked

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS If I remember right, the `return false;` inside of the [DOM Ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) was in effect canceling all other methods defined within.

Comment: Ohhh I didn't even see that one! Yes that def might of caused the problem, I was referring to the one just inside of a jQuery event